# How to use PHP variable in Jquery Ajax success request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have page which shows number of routes. User click one and it sends an ajax request and save the selected route in database.

On the same page in different tab, I am running query which gets related information of the selected route. So i have `Where clause` in my query.

The problem is how I can feed in the ID of selected route to `Where clause` in my query in different tab

Here is code.

JQuery - When user click/select the route

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// capture the ID of clicked route
    $(".collection-routeselection").click( function(){
        route_id = $(this).attr("value");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '../data/collecting.php?action=route-selection?routeid='+route_id,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {'routeid':route_id},
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $("#tab1").removeClass("active");
                $("#tab2").addClass("active");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            //Display error message to user
                alert("An error occured when saving the data");
            }
        });
    });
```

So i send the selected route using ajax to update database table.

```
$insert_web1 = $mysqli_scs->prepare("INSERT INTO collectiontracking_ctr (idrou_ctr,tab_ctr,created_ctr,modified_ctr) VALUES (?,'tab1',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

 //bind paramaters
$rouid = "";
if (isset($_POST['routeid'])) {

    $rouid = $_POST['routeid'];

}

$insert_web1->bind_param("i",$rouid);

$insert_web1->execute();
```

All working perfect so far..now I have another query on the same page (in different tab) which should have a `where clause` of selected route.

My question is how can i bind the selected route id to the where clause on second query.

```
  $select_stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli_scs, "SELECT id_rou,idjtp_job
   FROM routes_rou 
    WHere  id_rou =?");
```

I want to populate ? with selected route ID.

Thanks

Comment: manipulating your DB directly from client is not a good idea in general, just so you know

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value you are interested in is `route_id`, you should be able to store that in a variable that is accessible to tab #2 if it isn't already. Since it's on the same page this should be trivial especially since you're using jquery.

I apologize if I'm misunderstanding the question. If so please elaborate.

Comment: Yes i do want **route_id** but how i can save that in php variable. I have save using JavaScript but PHP cannot read java script.

Comment: On the same page in different tab are you using ajax again to call `$select_stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli_scs, "SELECT id_rou,idjtp_job
   FROM routes_rou 
    WHere  id_rou =?");` If so I would just pass the `route_id` variable in the ajax call.